# Adding Border Implementation for widget on hover like in webflow

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In webflow when we hover over an element it shows a blue border.(See Video)
I am interested in knowing how it is implemented.
I have done my research and could make a basic guess of its implementation.

1 Listen to mouseover event on the body
2 then on mouseover update use document.getelementfrompoint() to get the element node at the point
Now using an absolutely positioned div add a border at the hovered node rect.

The question is my guess correct?
Is there a threshold amount that we need to check to avoid calling mousemove handler?

[image]

Comment: Seem like you could do that in CSS with a mix of [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), and [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline). No javascript required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is... I don't think there is any issue about the mousemove events firering a lot. I used no threshold at all (no debouncing).

**EDIT - Answer to OP question in comments**:

> Why didn't you use `e.target` instead of `document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)` ?

Good question! I tried the `.elementFromPoint()` method first because I didn't know about it before your question. And it worked well. It is called *"beginner's luck"*, I think! loll! -- Now I just  tried with `e.target` and saw the jumpy effect that motivated your question about a threshold.

The reason for the jumpy effect is simple. On `mousemove` the generated event object contains the target element, right? And that is the element under the pointer. Once, it is the wanted element... And second, it is the added *"border div"* from our script. And it cycles like this non-stop.

Now using `document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)`, it ALWAYS is the wanted element because two lines above in the script, we are removing the previous *"border div"* and THEN querying for the element under the pointer.

```js
function showElement(e) {

  // If there is already an appended div, remove it
  let prev = document.querySelector(".border")
  if(prev){
    prev.remove()
  }

  // Get the element. If there's none, stop here to avoid errors
  let elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)
  if(!elem){return}
  let elemTagname = elem.tagName.toLowerCase()
  let elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect()

  // Create a div to show the elem borders
  let border = document.createElement("div")
  border.classList.add("border")
  border.style.top = elemRect.top + "px"
  border.style.left = elemRect.left + "px"
  border.style.width = elemRect.width + "px"
  border.style.height = elemRect.height + "px"
  
  // Create a span to show the tag name
  let tag = document.createElement("span")
  tag.classList.add("tag")
  tag.innerText = elemTagname
  
  // Append!
  border.append(tag)
  document.documentElement.append(border)
}

// Mousemove handler
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", showElement)
```

```css
div{
  height: 300px;
}

.border{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.tag{
  background: lightgrey;
  color: blue;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I am curious to know why didn't you use "e.target"  instead of "document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)".

Comment: I edited with a long answer ;)